# Logo is not updating in Magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I had created custom theme in Magento 2. I had declared the theme logo in the app/design/frontend/Muneeb/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="logo">
<arguments>
<argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/m2-logo.png</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">350</argument>
<argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">350</argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

I have already clean the cache but the logo is not changing. Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

1- remove data of var and pub/static use following command

```
rm -rf *
```

on the respective folders

2- run the deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

3- provide appropriate permission to both var and pub/static in case
website show error

```
chmod -R 755 pub/static var
```

Comment: Your commands are misguiding , PLEASE DO NOT USE rm -rf * **IT WILL DELETE ALL THE FILES AND YOU WILL NOT BE ABLE TO RECOVER THEM
@abhinav DO REMOVE YOUR ANSWER OR EDIT THE COMMAND TO**
rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache